# Bind component variable to pipe filter

Tags: angular, angular2-pipe, angular2-custom-pipes

i have a problem when passing values to my pipe filter. I need to pass an argument value in the form of a variable called pagex from my component and I cant find the syntax to make it work... or I'm missing something. Thanks for the help.

**myComponent**

```
export class ItemsComponent { 
    items:any[]
    pagex:number;

constructor(private ItemService:ItemService){
    this.ItemService.getItems()
    .subscribe(items =>{
        this.items=items;
        this.pagex=2;
    });
}
```

The following, passing the value manually, works:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items| myfilter: '2'">
```

and this doesnt, tried already many combinations...

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items| myfilter: {{pagex}}">
<div *ngFor="let item of items| myfilter: '{{pagex}}'">
<div *ngFor="let item of items| myfilter: {{pagex.toString()}}">
<div *ngFor="let item of items| myfilter: pagex>
<div *ngFor="let item of items| myfilter:'pagex'>
```

**mypipe**

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'myfilter',
})
export class MyFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(items: any[], args: any[]): any {
        if(items!=undefined){

        console.log(args[0])
        var maxItems = 5;
           var start_index= (args[0]*maxItems)-maxItems-1;
           var end_index= args[0]*maxItems;
    return items.filter((item, index) => (index > start_index) && (index <end_index));
    }
}
```

}

Comment: check out my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have made mistake in the filter input's type.

The parameters to the filter must be of number type and not **any[ ]**

```
import{PipeTransform,Pipe} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name:'myFilter'
})

export class myFilter implements PipeTransform{

    transform(inputDate:string,integerValue:number):string{
      console.log(integerValue);

      return integerValue.toString();             
    }
}
```

I dont know what is the filter doing exactly and **there is no service** implemented. So I tried this way. You can check the plunker below

[**LIVE DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/Yl7lpS2loVGEa0LM1tHb?p=preview)

Comment: That was the mistake! argument should have been number... thanks for your time and effort!

Comment: I wasn't getting any error in the console. Just nothing was happening

Answer (score -1):

EDIT. Try this, seems you are missing the: `' '`

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items| myfilter: '{{pagex}}'">
```

Comment: Sorry i screwed it copying the code, the first line was wrong , I edited the post: <div *ngFor="let item of items| myfilter: '2'">

Comment: No, throws an error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined ("
        
    </div>
        <div [ERROR ->]*ngFor="let item of items| myfilter: {{pagex.toString()}}">
        <div class="row">
        <div "): ItemsComponent@10:13
Can't bind to '*ngFor' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. ("